# ¿Cómo puedo llamar un file en función de seleccionar un item de una lista de un input?

Tags: php, html5, ajax

Continuo con el diseñando del formulario para un cajero de ventas, el objetivo que busco en este momento es :

En función de un input box se crea un listado y este genera el autocompletar en base a lo escrito (Lo cual ya funciona con el siguiente código listado en la parte de abajo).

El código que estoy usando para esto es el siguiente:

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {




    $('#key').on('keyup', function() {
        var key = $(this).val();    

        var dataString = 'key='+key;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add_salecar.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                //Escribimos las sugerencias que nos manda la consulta
                $('#suggestions').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                //Al hacer click en algua de las sugerencias
                $('.suggest-element').on('click', function(){
                        //Obtenemos la id unica de la sugerencia pulsada
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        //Editamos el valor del input con data de la sugerencia pulsada
                        $('#key').val($('#'+id).attr('data'));
                        $('#key').val('');

                        //Hacemos desaparecer el resto de sugerencias
                        $('#suggestions').fadeOut(1000);
                        alert('Has seleccionado el '+id+' '+$('#'+id).attr('data'));                        
                        location.reload();
                        return false;                            
                });
            }
        });
    });
}); 

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">        
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
            <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="#">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key" id="key" placeholder="Buscar...">
                </div>
            </form>

            <div id="suggestions"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

add_salecar.php

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'whare_inv');

$connexion = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

$html = '';
$key = $_POST['key'];

$result = $connexion->query(
    'SELECT * FROM products     
    WHERE status = 1 and 
    name  LIKE "%'.strip_tags($key).'%"
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5');


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                
        $html .= '<div><a class="suggest-element" data="'.utf8_encode($row['name']).'" id="product'.$row['id'].'">'.utf8_encode($row['name']).'</a></div>';
    }
}
echo $html;
?>
```

El apoyo que necesito es para saber como realizar el código para que del listado mostrado, al seleccionar un item de dicho listado mandar llamar un archivo php para realizar la inserción de un registro en la base de datos en base a dicho item seleccionado.

Nota: Actualmente el código que he mostrado realiza la función de obtener un listado de la base de datos y realizar la búsqueda dentro del mismo input box a modo de autocompletar.

De antemano gracias por su apoyo.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo básicamente ya lo tienes hecho, sólo falta que en vez de la alerta que levantas, envíes un segundo llamado ajax, esta vez a un endpoint que persiste el producto seleccionado:

```
$('.suggest-element').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#key').val($(this).text());

  return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'persist_selection.php',
    data: {product_id: id}
  }).then(() => {
    $('#suggestions').fadeOut(1000);
    return;
  });
});
```

Pero si ya tienes un formulario en pantalla, puede que sea mejor que le añadas un input con el id del producto,

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name">
  <input type="text" name="product_id" id="product_id">
</form>
```

y luego envíes el formulario completo por ajax:

```
$('.suggest-element').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#product_name').val($(this).text());
  $('#product_id').val(id);
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'persist_selection.php',
    data: $('#form').serialize()
  }).then(() => {
    $('#suggestions').fadeOut(1000);
    return;
  });
});
```

Respecto a tu listener sobre el keyup sobre la caja de texto, fíjate que cada vez que escribes se está gatillando un llamado ajax. Para cuando has escrito una palabra se encolaron 10 llamados que no eran necesarios. En el siguiente ejemplo te dejo una implementación donde el llamado ajax está `debounced`.

En vez de

```
 function llenaSugerencias() { .... }

 $('#keyproduct_name').on('keyup', llenaSugerencias);
```

Declaras un timer para que se gatille el llenado 500ms después. Si se invoca el listener en menos de 500ms, se resetea el timer (luego la invocación original no se ejecuta) y fija otro timer:

```
function llenaSugerencias() { .... }

$('#product_name').on('keyup', () => {
  this.timer = this.timer || null;
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
  this.timer = setTimeout(llenaSugerencias, 500);
});
```

En otras palabras, si escribes 10 letras con intervalos menores de 500ms, sólo se gatilla el último (puse 500 arbitrariamente).

```js
var mockup_autocompletar = [{
    "id": 40011,
    "name": "Lenovo IdeaPad 320-14"
  },
  {
    "id": 37462,
    "name": "HP Pavilion 15-CD006LA"
  },
  {
    "id": 35626,
    "name": "Dell Alienware 17"
  },
  {
    "id": 31754,
    "name": "ASUS VivoBook E402NA-GA034T"
  },
  {
    "id": 37471,
    "name": "Apple MacBook Air MQD32CI/A"
  }
];

function returnJSON(data) {
  var blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([data], {
      type: 'application/json'
    })
  );

  return blob;
}

async function llamadoAjax(payload, delay = 1000) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('trayendo sugerencias');
      $.get(
        returnJSON(JSON.stringify(payload))
      ).then(resolve);
    }, delay);
  });
}

async function llenaSugerencias() {
  $('#suggestions').empty().fadeOut(1000);
  let productos = await llamadoAjax(mockup_autocompletar) || [];
  $('#suggestions').fadeIn(1000);
  productos.forEach(producto => {
    let option = $('<option class="suggest-element"/>');
    option.prop('value', producto.id)
      .data('product', producto)
      .text(producto.name)
      .appendTo('#suggestions');
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#alert').on('click', '.close', () => {
    $('#alert').removeClass('show');
  });
  $('#suggestions').on('click', () => {
    let selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if (!selectedOption) {
      return;
    }
    let selectedProduct = selectedOption.data('product'),
      form = $('#product_name').closest('form');
    $('#product_name').val(selectedProduct.name);
    $('#product_id').val(selectedProduct.id);

    $('#suggestions').empty().fadeOut(1000);
    $('#alert').addClass('show');
    $('#alert').find('pre').text(`Enviando POST con datos del producto...`);
    llamadoAjax(selectedProduct, 2000)
      .then(res => {
        $('#alert').find('pre').text(`Producto enviado: 
          ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);

      });
  });
  $('#product_name').on('keyup', () => {
    this.timer = this.timer || null;
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(llenaSugerencias, 500);
  });

});
```

```css
#suggestions {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#suggestions option {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#suggestions option:hover {
  background-color: #ececec;
}

#alert {
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
      <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm w-100">
          <input class="wsearch_query form-control w-50" type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Buscar..." />
          <input class="ml-5 form-control " type="text" name="product_id" id="product_id" placeholder="#id" readonly />
        </div>
      </form>



      <select id="suggestions" class="custom-select" style="display:none" size="5">
      </select>
      <div id="alert" class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade" role="alert">
        <pre></pre>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amenadiel, me ayudo mucho tu consejo, comprendo tu sugerencia  y he podido encontrar solución a mi problema, .